# R Dynamically filter rows in dataframe based on unique combination of listed columns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyeval, nse

I have a large dataset (49 columns with 16000 rows) in long format.  Ultimately, I need to **filter the dataset by unique combinations of user defined specific columns** in order to plot other dynamically chosen columns.  The plotting will be done using ggplots2 and facets (x,y,facet_column, facet_row, colorbin).

Rather than show my large dataset, I put together a much smaller example using 'mtcars' dataset to illustrate my issue. I have the columns outputting correct, but with out a series of for loops, I can't figure out how to change the subset.

**Set up data:**

```
#Load needed libraries
library("dplyr", "tidyr", "ggplot2")

#Convert row.names into a column that can be called
data <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "Names")

#Declare groups:
#group_rows are the columns that I need to filter my data based on the unique combinations
#  Ultimately, I want to create a new plot of group_cols based on these rows
group_rows <- list(list('cyl', 'gear'), list('vs', 'carb'))
#group_cols are the columns I want included in the plot
group_cols <- list(list('Names', 'mpg','cyl', 'gear'), list('Names', 'wt','vs', 'carb'))
```

**This works and produces the output I need, but is SUPER not convenient**

Since I am NOT dynamically filtering the "group_rows" variable, I have to repeat the loop for each list variation in group_rows. In my example I only have two  variables in each list of my group_rows, but in my actual dataset, I *could* have significantly more.

```
# Do group_rows 1
for (c in group_cols){
  for (var_cyl in unique(data$cyl)){
    for (var_gear in unique(data$gear)){
     df <- data %>%
        filter(cyl==var_cyl &gear==var_gear) %>%
        select_(.dots = c)
      # enter my plotting function
    }
  }
}
# Do group_rows 2
for (c in group_cols){
  for (var_vs in unique(data$vs)){
    for (var_carb in unique(data$carb)){
      df <- data %>%
        filter(vs==var_vs &carb==var_carb) %>%
        select_(.dots = c)

      # enter my plotting function
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a manually created plot that shows your expected output?

Comment: I can't with this example data (because I was trying to get more at the filtering rows), but if you think it would be helpful, I could add the output with my large dataset.

Comment: It is very difficult to help without representative data and expected output.

Comment: I added my actual dataset and figures as a snipit.  Let me know if there is anything else that I can do to help clarify things.

Comment: I think there is a good chance I can help you do what you want, but unfortunately, your question isn't in a form I can understand. Please provide a working dataset that **we can run** as well as the parameters you expect to pass and the expected output. Your newest edit makes the question far too broad. Please make your question as minimal as it needs to be to help you past your roadblock.

Comment: Thank you Ian, your answer got me close, so I bet you could figure it out too.  I updated my question to hopefully be more clear.  The part that I am having issue with is filtering the rows to include in a subset data.frame.  From the very gross code I added, I hope it is clear where my issue is. My subsetting the columns and plotting is fine.

Comment: See https://github.com/alan-y/blogdown-website/issues/2#issuecomment-628704193 for an approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `parse_expr` from `rlang` as well as `purrr`

I've made a slight modification to your `group_rows` to include some filtering:

```
group_rows <- list(list("cyl==4", "&", "gear==4"), list("vs==1", "&", "carb==4"))

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
map2(group_cols,group_rows,
     ~ data %>%
          dplyr::select(unlist(.x)) %>%
          dplyr::filter(!!parse_expr(paste(.y,collapse = "")))
     )
[[1]]
           Names  mpg cyl gear
1     Datsun 710 22.8   4    4
2      Merc 240D 24.4   4    4
3       Merc 230 22.8   4    4
4       Fiat 128 32.4   4    4
5    Honda Civic 30.4   4    4
6 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4    4
7      Fiat X1-9 27.3   4    4
8     Volvo 142E 21.4   4    4

[[2]]
      Names   wt vs carb
1  Merc 280 3.44  1    4
2 Merc 280C 3.44  1    4
```

It's not clear to me how you intend to plot 4 columns. But you can use `walk2` in place of `map2` and just have your function plot whatever you want.

Comment: I need to use ggplot in a facet wrapper in order to plot the columns_group being something like (x,y,facet_column, facet_row,color).  The hiccup I still have with this code is that the rows are still explictly declared (cyl==4) rather than dynamically listed.  I need a set of plots for each unique combination of cyl and gear columns.